# Создание своего DropBox

Tags: windows, android, java, macos, linux

Здравствуйте. Задался целью на java написать программку по аналогии как dropbox. Основная цель - сделать программу кроссплатформенной (винты, линукс, мак, андроид). Но так как я новичок в этой сфере то возникают вопросы:

1. на сколько код написанный для  ПК, будет совместим с андроидом? Поверхностно столкнулся с андроидом, и сложилось ощущение что в нем не все доступно, что доступно в других ОС.
2. надо отслеживать изменения в папке, чтобы отсылать данные на сервер, как это реализовать - таймер или прямое обращение к функциям ОС, опять же как это будет выглядеть под андроидом?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: > таймер или прямое обращение к функциям ОС

выбор у Вас конечно странный.

Comment: для новичка вполне приемлемый, подскажите другой вариант, если возможно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ощущение верное, не все что есть в vanilla Java - реализовано Android'е
2. Надо брать таймстамп времени модификации файла и в случае расхождений постить через http на облако. Лучше всего через фоновый поток с проверкой по таймеру - будет работать везде и на desktop'е и на Android'е

**Update**

Немного устаревший список отличий а реализации API между J2SE и Android [здесь](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/java-vs-android-apis/504)

Здесь надо понимать, что Java в Android'е и десктопе полностью совместимы на уровне синтаксиса Java 6, но Android'е отсутствует реализация некоторых (порой довольно значимых) частей J2SE и обратно также верно - в J2SE нет много из того, что есть в Android'е. Отдельно добавлю, что кардинальное отличие между Android и vanilla Java  кроется в формате объектных файлов. Все это как раз и есть суть бесконечных судебных тяжб между Oracle и Google.

Comment: где-нибудь есть, например в виде таблицы, эти различия java?

Comment: да нет там различий в java. Там разница в идеологии.

Comment: то есть любой код для десктопа на 100% будет работать и под андроидом???

Comment: @KoVadim ты неправ - есть некоторые функции/методы J2SE нереализованные в Android'е

Comment: различия есть и весьма существенные http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_Android_API

Comment: Я себе смутно представляю awt/swing на телефоне. Другие детали - особенности реалиации.

>> то есть любой код для десктопа на 100% будет работать и под андроидом???

нет. и не по причине якобы "различий java". А в том, что архитектуру кода под андроид нужно писать принципиально по другому. Все попытки писать под андроид как под декстоп приводят к печальным последствиям.

(пример - в андоиде любое окно может быть закрыто без предупреждения. Данные нужно сохранять. Или на декстопе память java программисты обычно не считают, а на андроиде это один с важных параметров).

Comment: Извините за оффтоп, но после фразы "винты, линукс, мак, андроид" я понял, что здесь советовать нечего.
У меня главный вопрос - на чём хранить файлы и на чём будет храниться информация о последнем доступе к файлу? Без сервера, который будет отслеживать эту информацию у Вас ничего не получится.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit ТС как раз вроде и предполагал сервер, разве не так?

Comment: Что именно будет делать сервер? У автора написано, что туда будет отсылаться информация об изменении. Эта информация не так важна, если на сервере не будет храниться именно самый последний вариант файла. А реализовать нужно с помощью какой-то службы, которая составит список всех файлов и будет периодически (через тот же AlarmManager в Android) проверять этот список.